# Upload IfromFile in a dto with asp.net minimal API's

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible too upload files from a DTO with asp.net minimal api's ?

I've tried this:

```
public class MyDto
{
    public string BlaBlaBla { get; set; }
    public List<ListOfUselessStuff> MyList { get; set; }
    public IFormFile MyFile { get; set; }
}
```

Endpoint

```
app.MapPost("MyRoute", DoStuff)
   .WithTags("Tags")
   .Accepts<MyDto>("multipart/form-data")
   .Produces<NewlyCreatedDto>(200)
   .ProducesValidationProblem(400)
   .ProducesProblem(401)
   .ProducesProblem(403)
   .RequireAuthorization(Policies.RequireAdmin);
```

And finally Do Stuff:

```
private async Task<IResult> CreateQuestion([FromServices]IMediator mediator, [FromForm] MyDto dto)
{
                    //do stuff
}
```

But I just manage too get:

> "Expected a supported JSON media type but got "multipart/form-data;
> boundary=---------------------------29663231333811935594178759367"."

Comment: try change IFormFile to byte[]

Comment: I've tried that without success.

Comment: you send data with ajax or normal form?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but it's a normal form. Tried with postman / swagger.

Comment: @Paperbagger any solution? I have same problem.

Comment: No, Sadly not. I did end up getting the file from the HttpContext.Form, which did end up pretty ugly. but it works.

Answer (score 1):

This has been addressed with .NET 7. Support for IFormFile and IFormFileCollection has been added. You should be able to use it in your MediatR pipelines.

Ref: [.NET 7 Minimal API Support for File Upload Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-7.0?source=recommendations&view=aspnetcore-7.0#file-uploads-using-iformfile-and-iformfilecollection)

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.MapPost("/upload", async (IFormFile file) =>
{
    var tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
    app.Logger.LogInformation(tempFile);
    using var stream = File.OpenWrite(tempFile);
    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
});

app.MapPost("/upload_many", async (IFormFileCollection myFiles) =>
{
    foreach (var file in myFiles)
    {
        var tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
        app.Logger.LogInformation(tempFile);
        using var stream = File.OpenWrite(tempFile);
        await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
    }
});

app.Run();
```

Comment: Also to add more context, as of .NET 7, uploading a single file or multiple files is supported directly. But if you want to add form data in the body along with file(s), it is not supported. It _maybe_ supported in .NET 8 and is on the .NET 8 Backlog. 

Ref: [Minimal API Github 39430](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39430)

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no support for binding form forms but there will be in the future according to ASP.NET Core official documentation.

> No support for binding from forms. This includes binding IFormFile. We plan to add support for IFormFile in the future.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#differences-between-minimal-apis-and-apis-with-controllers

What you can do is inject the HttpRequest and access the form property as in this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/71499716/11618303.